# Workflow log file in Microsoft CRM Dynamics

Tags: workflow, microsoft-dynamics

Where is the log file for any Workflow located in CRM Dynamics

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain what kind of log are you looking for?

Comment: Hi Andrii Butenko A workflow is a a process that runs in the background. There has to be a place where it tells me when a specific workflow ran last time and whether it ended successfully or not. This is what I mean by a workflow log. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing with your knowledge of workflows. I will add my 5 cents. Since CRM 2013 we have not only background workflows but real-time workflows as well. All workflows are entity and record specific. For every workflow customizer can configure option to delete workflow execution log or not after successful execution or not (so if cleaning checkbox is checked and workflow was executed without any errors - there will be no log of execution of workflow). But if it is not you can find all 'logs' under Async Job entities.

Comment: Thanks Andrii :) I am guessing you're referring to "System Job" entity. I found all the logs in there :)